# How to ordered GroupListView items by date?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `GroupListView` on Flutter to show messages from Firestore, where I grouped my messages by the message sent date with descending order. Although the messages are grouped as I wanted, Flutter can't seem to sort the groups correctly by their date format.

Is there any solution for this?

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
// list of messages in chatroom
showMessages() {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: chats,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      return snapshot.hasData
        ? GroupedListView(
          reverse: true,
            elements: snapshot.data.docs, 
            groupBy: (QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>? document) =>
              DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(document?.get('messageCreatedTime'))),
            order: 
              GroupedListOrder.DESC,
            groupSeparatorBuilder: (value) => 
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4, 
                  vertical: 10),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 2),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
                ),
                child: Text(
                  value.toString(), 
                  // convertTimeToString(value),
                  style: greySmall, textAlign: TextAlign.center)
              ),
            itemBuilder: (context, elements) =>
              MessageTile(
                messageText: elements!['messageText'], 
                messageSentTime: elements['messageCreatedTime'], 
                sentByMe: elements['messageSenderId'] == DatabaseService().getCurrentUserId(),
              )
            )
        : Container();
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary solution by changing the dateformat used on groupBy to `DateFormat.yMd()`

here is the updated code

```
showMessages() {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: chats,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      return snapshot.hasData

        ? GroupedListView(
          reverse: true,
            elements: snapshot.data.docs, 
            groupBy: (QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>? document) =>
                DateFormat.yMd().format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(document?.get('messageCreatedTime'))),
            order: 
              GroupedListOrder.DESC,
            groupSeparatorBuilder: (value) => 
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4, 
                  vertical: 10),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 2),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
                ),
                child: Text(
                  value,
                  style: greySmall, textAlign: TextAlign.center)
              ),

            itemBuilder: (context, elements) =>
              MessageTile(
                messageText: elements!['messageText'], 
                messageSentTime: elements['messageCreatedTime'], 
                sentByMe: elements['messageSenderId'] == DatabaseService().getCurrentUserId(),
              )
            )
        : Container();
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code:

```
showMessages() {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: chats,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      return snapshot.hasData
        ? GroupedListView(
          reverse: true,
            elements: snapshot.data.docs, 
            groupBy: (QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>? document) =>
              DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(document?.get('messageCreatedTime')),
            order: 
              GroupedListOrder.DESC,
            groupComparator: (DateTime value1, DateTime value2) =>
              value2.compareTo(value1),
            groupSeparatorBuilder: (value) => 
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4, 
                  vertical: 10),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 2),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
                ),
                child: Text(
                  DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(value), 
                  style: greySmall, textAlign: TextAlign.center)
              ),
            itemBuilder: (context, elements) =>
              MessageTile(
                messageText: elements!['messageText'], 
                messageSentTime: elements['messageCreatedTime'], 
                sentByMe: elements['messageSenderId'] == DatabaseService().getCurrentUserId(),
              )
            )
        : Container();
    }
  );
}
```

by the code I've used, you are grouping by `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` not `DateFormat` at first.

happy coding...

Comment: it returns error `NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance getter 'millisecondsSinceEpoch'.
Receiver: 1680017092052
Tried calling: millisecondsSinceEpoch)`, what does adding .millisecondsSinceEpoch do?

Comment: For example, DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1680017092052) returns a DateTime object representing the date and time corresponding to the timestamp 1680017092052.

Comment: please check the new edited answer and let me know.

Comment: thank you, I've tried the code. The order works fine now with a little changes on comparator, its suppose to be `value1.compareTo(value2)`. But this method grouped the message by DATETIME which include hh:mm:ss making every message sent as individual group.

Comment: your welcome, as a matter of fact, I did not access to the datas you're using to see what is goin on exactly. anyway I'm so happy that I could help you even a little.

Comment: I saw that you inserted the correct answer yourself. so please mark your answer as correct one, and if my answer helped you please vote it up to help another people. have a nice coding my friend.